# SQL: retrieving timestamps given multiple conditions

Tags: sql

I am struggling with the following piece of SQL problem.

I have a table containing different activities for different users and a timestamp of the activity:

```
Usercode   Activity_ID   Sequence_ID   TimeStamp
-------------------------------------------------
   1       Packing_01       1          15:02
   1       Packing_01       2          15:03
   2       Packing_02       1          15:04  
   2       Packing_02       3          15:07
   1       Packing_05       1          16:03
   1       Packing_05       1          16:06
```

What I would like to achieve is per Usercode and Activity to get the timestamps from the first and last sequence_ID.

Something Like this

```
Usercode   Activity     Start_Work   End_Work
----------------------------------------------
    1      Packing_01   15:02        15:03
    1      Packing_05   16:03        16:06
    2      Packing_02   15:03        15:07
```

What I can do is

```
SELECT 
    Usercode, Activity, MIN(TimeStamp), MAX(TimeStamp)
FROM 
    table
GROUP BY
    Usercode, Activity
```

But this goes wrong at midnight and is not clean. So I would like to look at the min and max Sequence_ID, given a set of (Usercode, Activity) and return the respective timestamps. I tried to do this for some time using subqueries but couldn't quite make it work.

Thanks in advance!

Sorry if the question is unclear, this is my first time posting here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want full rows think "filtering" not "aggregation".  So, I think you want something like this:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.timestamp = (select min(t2.timestamp) from t t2 where t2.usercode = t.usercode
                    ) or
      t.timestamp = (select max(t2.timestamp) from t t2 where t2.usercode = t.usercode
                    );
```